# Django idiomatic group test in templates

Tags: python, django, django-views

Been browsing the net for a few days looking for a straight forward way to do something like the following using standard User/Group functionality:

```
{% if user.is_in_group 'foo' %}
    <p>Hello Foo user</p>
{% endif %}
```

Extending the Django user class doesn't seem very nice, and i'm not sure if a filter can be used to produce a boolean for an if. Adding a user_groups list to the context seems scruffy.

What would be the sanest way to approach this in Django?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A filter can certainly return a boolean to be used in an if, and that is by far the best solution here. Extending the User class wouldn't help because you can't pass a parameter to a method in a template anyway.

The filter could be as simple as:

```
@register.filter
def is_in_group(user, group_name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()
```

and you would use it like this:

```
{% if user|is_in_group:"foo" %}
```

Comment: Lovely stuff. Thank you.